# Android application for upgrading an external mother board

Tags: android, bluetooth

**Background:**

We created an Android app that currently communicates with an external mother board via Bluetooth connection.  The board in-turn issues commands to run one or more motor(s) at different speeds. (This application was built for a specific task in the marine industry)

Our goal is to enhance the application so that android mobile users (in the future) will be able to upgrade the motherboard's firmware by issuing a command on the application connected via Bluetooth.

The motherboard uses an old standard communications protocol called `YMODEM`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YMODEM The mother board supports this function and we are currently able to handle the firmware upgrade using hyper terminal on a windows platform.

**My question is**:

Is it possible to use the YMODEM protocol in an android application to perform a re-flash?

If yes, how? Any help would be appreciated!!Thanks for looking into this!

Answer (score 7):

Apologies for the late response, but it might be helpful...  Yes, it is definitely possible. I have done exactly this with a nexus 7 and an external device with an ARM processor. The nexus 7 must be rooted with USB debugging enabled. I used [wugfresh's](http://www.wugfresh.com/dev/nexus-root-toolkit/) nexus root toolkit -- it was very easy.

Next (hold onto your seats), you must write your application to use the YModem protocol.  One option is to use the android NDK (Native development kit) to compile a YModem protocol written in C/C++ (Try [Tixy's](http://yxit.co.uk/source/index.html#Y-Modem)).  You'll need *cygwin* or *mingw* before you install the NDK if you're working with Windows.

So let's say your using windows and you have the NDK installed in `c:\android-ndk-r8b-windows\android-ndk-r8b`.  You can use Eclipse with the adt plugin installed, and let's say your new workspace for the project is c:\android-workspace.  You can use a batch file to execute NDK make from your project (`c:\android-workspace\batch.bat`):

```
C:\android-ndk-r8b-windows\android-ndk-r8b\ndk-build.cmd 
PAUSE
```

Just make sure you export the C/C++ functions so that they can be used by your JAVA android application.

Interface.cpp:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include "ymodem_tx.h"
#include "ymodem_main.h"

extern "C" {

JNIEXPORT int JNICALL Java_com_example_ymupload_MainActivity_ymodemSent( JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, int portNumber, jstring fileName)
{
    int status = 0;
    if (portNumber >= 0)
    {
        const char* input = env->GetStringUTFChars(fileName, 0);

        status = ymodem_sentFile(portNumber, input);

        env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(fileName, input);
    }
    else
    {
        status = 0xFF;
    }

    return status;
}


JNIEXPORT int JNICALL Java_com_example_ymupload_MainActivity_YmodemGetTotalSize( JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
{
    return ymodem_getTotalSize();
}


JNIEXPORT int JNICALL Java_com_example_ymupload_MainActivity_YmodemGetTransferredSize( JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
{
    return ymodem_getTransferredSize();
}



JNIEXPORT bool JNICALL Java_com_example_ymupload_MainActivity_YmodemIsSending( JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
{
    return ymodem_bIsSending();
}

JNIEXPORT int JNICALL Java_com_example_ymupload_MainActivity_YmodemGetStatus( JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
{
return ymodem_uGetStatus();
}


JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_ymupload_MainActivity_YmodemGetFileName( JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
{
    return env->NewStringUTF(ymodem_pGetFileName());
}


}
```

Also make sure you put that file and other `.c`, `.cpp`, `.h` files in the `jni` folder in your project folder, e.g. `c:\android-workspace\prog-name\jni`, along with an `Android.mk` file (there are plenty of other stack questions about `Android.mk` files).

You can put the binaries that you want to flash in a folder on the `/sdcard/`. Download a file browser to see them.