# Android ymodem over bluetooth in Java

Tags: android, bluetooth, file-transfer

Has anyone successfully implemented ymodem in java to send files over bluetooth (SPP)?

I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802506/android-application-for-upgrading-an-external-mother-board) option and wouldn't mind trying to compile some C/C++ code for Android but I do not want to root the tablet, is it really needed? why?

Comment: SPP or RFCOMM? I might be barking mad, but from memory SPP is built on top of RFCOMM which is essentially a raw data stream.

Comment: Yes , SPP is on top of RFCOMM.
From the spec:
Baseband > LMP & L2CAP > RFCOMM & SDP > Serial port emulation or other API.

Official documentation on Bluetooth.org
Where RFCOMM is the transport protocol and SDP is the Service Discovery Protocol

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12907192/2760919) is a very good explanation about how to transfer data using **ymodem** protocol trough [**Tixy**](http://yxit.co.uk/source/index.html#Y-Modem)'s implementation on Android.

I think that a **rooted** device is necessary because your application needs low level access to the serial interface/modem in order to transmit data following the *[ymodem specification](http://www.techfest.com/hardware/modem/xymodem.htm)* (without any high-level incapsulation extra-data) .

Answer (score 1):

You need to root because serial communication in android (and other linux systems) always go over `/dev/ttys..`

And the permissions for `/dev/ttys..` is usually set to `rw` for `root` only.

It might be that on some android roms there is access to the devices, but usually that wont be the case.

**But** if you are able to send raw data over bluetooth (java), you need to modify the ymodem source code that it returns the data pack. Send the returned data pack and you are on a good way.

*EDIT*

There are some ways to send raw packages:
http://www.intorobotics.com/how-to-develop-simple-bluetooth-android-application-to-control-a-robot-remote/