# YModem protocol over Android using Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin, legacy

I have been looking for an answer but I only found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802506/android-application-for-upgrading-an-external-mother-board)

If I am using UsbDeviceConnection can I implement the YModem protocol using C# code? I don't need to root the device considering that I am using a "serial port" to implement the communication, right?

Comment: You can use a project like https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android as it supports the most popular USB<->Serial chipsets to avoid directly talking to /dev/tty*** that almost always requires root as the perms on stock roms only allow RW for root/root. Adding a X/YModem implementation on top of that would be easy, most C versions of X/YModem  are 50 lines and less... and I would assume there are a few C# versions floating around that you could adapt.

Comment: Yes, I already have some YModem code here from an old Visual Basic project and I also some Usb as Serial code, I just wanted to know if there was some Android specific implementation without the need to root the device.
Thank you for your answer, I will try to run some tests with what I have.

Comment: Hello @CristopherGarza where you able to implement YModem successfully for Android?